# What is the asymptotic time-complexity (big theta) of T(n) = log(n*n!)?

Tags: big-o

I think is O(n*log(n)) but I am not sure.

I tried log(n*n!) = log(n(n *n-1*n-2* ...* 1)) = n*log(n) + log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(1) <= nlog(n) + nlog(n) = 2n*log(n)

Can someone explain if this is correct?

Comment: The result is correct, although it is unclear where the first `n log(n)` term comes from.

Comment: log(n*n!) = log(n(n *n-1*n-2* ...* 1)) = log(n^2*n(n-1)*n(n-2)*...*n1) = log(n) + log(n) + log(n) + log(n-1) + log(n) + log(n-2) + ... + log(n) + log(1) = n*log(n) + log(n) + log(n-1) +log(n-2) + ... + log(1) <= n*log(n) + n*log(n). Is it correct?

Comment: Where does the n^2 come from? Your expansion of the parentheses is very wrong.

Comment: I was completely wrong. log(n*n!) = log(n(n *n-1*n-2* ...* 1)) = log(n* n* n-1*n-2*...*1) = log(n) + log(n) +log(n-1) + ... + log(1) <= log(n) + log(n)*(n-1) = (n-1+1)*log(n) = n*log(n)

Answer (score 0):

## Upper bound

```
log(n*n!) = log(n) + log(n!)
          = log(n) + log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(2)
         <= log(n) + (n-1)log(n)
          = n*log(n)
```

## Lower bound

```
log(n*n!) = log(n) + log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(2)
         >= log(n) + (n-1)/2*log(n/2)                     ; 1st half >= log(n/2), 2nd >= 0
         >= log(n/2) + (n-1)/2*log(n/2)
          = (n+1)/2*log(n/2)
         >= (n/2)log(n/2)
```

**Note:** *Here I'm assuming `log(2)>0`, which is true if we are taking base-2 logarithms. This is a valid assumption because the relationship between logarithms of different bases is linear, and linear relationships are preserved by big-O.*

**Intuitively**, we see that this is `O(n*log(n))`, right? But **why** is this true?

To see the reason we need to find `C > 0` and `N0` such that

```
           (N0/2)log(N0/2) >= C*N0*log(N0)
```

which reduces to:

```
           log(N0/2)/log(N0) >= 2*C
```

or

```
           1 - log(2)/log(N0) >= 2*C
```

so, choosing `C < 1/2`, v.g. `C = 1/4`, the value of `N0` only needs to verify:

```
           log(N0) >= 2*log(2) = log(4).
```

so it is enough to pic `N0 = 4`.

Note that we had one inequality for two constants `C` and `N0`. This is why we had to pick one (which was good enough), and the deduce the other.